# How to define vue.config.js to production?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have created my first SPA Vue project. It works locally, but not on a server. I wrote the server with node.js and made a production build from vue-front as 'dist' and put it to root of server.

It works otherwise, but when I refresh the browser or manually navigate to the page, I get the error `unknown endpoint` from my server. In stage of development I needed only this in vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      "/api/*": {
        target: "http://localhost:3003",
        secure: false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my router.js I have set base: process.env.BASE_URL, which came as default when I created the app. I read somewhere that nowadays one should use a variable `publicPath`?

```
...
Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
    },
...
```

So how do I build for production with vue.config.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your express server has to redirect the routes(your client routes) to index.html

Native Node.js example:

```
 const http = require('http')
 const fs = require('fs')
 const httpPort = 80

 http.createServer((req, res) => {
   fs.readFile('index.htm', 'utf-8', (err, content) => {
     if (err) {
       console.log('We cannot open "index.htm" file.')
     }

     res.writeHead(200, {
       'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
     })

     res.end(content)
   })
 }).listen(httpPort, () => {
   console.log('Server listening on: http://localhost:%s', httpPort)
 })
```

or you can use connect-history-api-fallback middleware for express https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback#usage

Or you can do it by hands like following

```
// Server index.html page when request is made
const clientRoutes = ['/', '/home', 'login', 'workspace']
app.get(clientRoutes, function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html')
  })
```

Comment: @Mikko If it helped you, mark this as the answer, please.